# Updating DataGrid cell checkbox after editing was done in another cell of the DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid bound to an ObservableCollection

```
    <DataGrid Name="dgWork" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TranslationData}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" Height="206"
              CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              RowEditEnding="dgWork_RowEditEnding">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Original" Binding="{Binding Path=Original}" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSort="False" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Translated" Binding="{Binding Path=Translated}" CanUserSort="False" />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is Translated" Binding="{Binding Path=IsTranslated, Converter={StaticResource translatedConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserSort="False" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

TranslationData is a property as following:

```
    public ObservableCollection<XLIFFData> _xliffData = new ObservableCollection<XLIFFData>();
    public ObservableCollection<XLIFFData> TranslationData { get { return _xliffData; } }
```

When the Translated text gets updated:

```
        DataGridRow dgRow = e.Row;
        //Update the _doc for the Row Id if original != translated
        //Update the _doc translated to equal true
        var localData = (XLIFFData) dgRow.Item;

        //Making presumption that even changing case is editing text
        if (localData.Original.Equals(localData.Translated)) return;

        foreach(var item in _xliffData)
        {
            if(item.Id == localData.Id)
            {
                item.Translated = localData.Translated;
                item.IsTranslated = "translated";
            }
        }
```

How can I also update the CheckBox to be checked off?

I tried updating the collection thinking the DataGrid will update I also tried the dgWork.Items.Refresh() command that fails with a statement this this not allowed on Edit or Add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to call Commit before setting your IsTranslated property. However there is the issue that modifying another value will call RowEndEditing a million times and crash. I had a similar problem with CellEndEdit. You can prevent this by trying the following code....

```
dgWork.CommitEdit()
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    new Action(delegate()
    {
        item.IsTranslated = true; /// << Assuming this is a bool for the checkbox??
        dgWork.Items.Refresh();
    }),
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if XLIFFData.IsTranslated raises property changed.
If it does I would advise looking the XLIFFData ViewModel as you should not need a converter on the checkbox column.  The ViewModel should handle updating anything related to that field unless I am misunderstanding the question.